# How to skip a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, if-statement

I want to update supplier information, and want to erase the content of the textbox txtWeb.

However when I debug it, it's always goes into the condition of my Regex to verify the content of the txtWeb textbox even the content of textbox is Empty. When I input correct URL in the textbox it's working fine, but it's not working whan there is no content.

However Database table allow null in txtWeb Column.

The problem is at the last "if" condition.

```
public void Modifier_Supplier()
        {
            SamsonEntities db = new SamsonEntities();
            try
            {
                action = "MODIF";
                if (gridSuppliers.CurrentRow != null && gridSuppliers.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null)
                {
                    SupplierDisplay supAct = (SupplierDisplay)gridSuppliers.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

                    Supplier supUpd = db.Suppliers.Single(sup => sup.SupplierID == supAct.SupplierID);

                    supUpd.SupplierName = txtNom.Text;
                    supUpd.Address = txtAdresse.Text;
                    supUpd.City = txtVille.Text;
                    supUpd.PostalCode = mskPostal.Text;
                    supUpd.Contact = txtContact.Text;
                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
                    Match match = regex.Match(txtCourriel.Text);
                    if (!match.Success)
                    {
                        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Ce courriel est invalide", "Message d'erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        supUpd.Email = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        supUpd.Email = txtCourriel.Text;
                    supUpd.Phone = mskPhone.Text;
                    Regex regexWeb = new Regex(@"^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)/?$");
                    Match matchWeb = regexWeb.Match(txtWeb.Text);
                    if (!matchWeb.Success)
                    {
                        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Ce site web est invalide", "Message d'erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        supUpd.Website = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        supUpd.Website = txtWeb.Text;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    FillSuppliers();

                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Fournisseur mis à jour", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you're saying the field can be blank why not add an or condition to allow ""?

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment?

Comment: My comment was saying exactly the answer that someone just posted. Check for an empty string and allow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, You dont want Regular expression validation when there is no text in txtWeb textbox. to do this, Just add a if condition to check that txtWeb is Empty or not.

```
if(txtWeb.Text != String.Empty)
  Match matchWeb = regexWeb.Match(txtWeb.Text);
```

Comment: All I have to do is to replace my last condition with your suggestion?

Comment: Why did you add the ASP.NET's tag?

Comment: Is this Q not belongs to ASP.NET? Is it Windows Application?

Comment: There's no ASP.NET in this application, it's a Windows Application